# Use and ArrayList to display data from an MVC Controller to a Razor Page

Tags: arraylist, model-view-controller, razor

I'm pretty new to working with Array Lists and would like to learn how to display data from the Controller that has an Array in the method to the MVC Razor Page. I'm creating a login that works just fine, but would like to display captured data from Active Directory to the UserLoginData.CSHTML page. I read that the best way is through the model. Any help would be greatly appreciated! (I just want the ArrayList in a table on the Razor data Page.)

Controller:

```
           public ActionResult UserLoginData(string username, string LblUserName, string 
    UserName, ArrayList AuthorizationGroups)
    {
        UserLoginModel model = new UserLoginModel();
        UserName = username;
        ViewBag.UserName = UserName;
        model.UserName = UserName;
        model.LblUserName = model.UserName;
        model.AuthorizationGroups = AuthorizationGroups;

        foreach (var item in AuthorizationGroups)
        {
             // Console.WriteLine(item);
            model.item = item;
        
        }
      
        
        
        return View(model);
    }
```

Model (Properties):

```
   //Labels for UserLoginData:

public string LblUserName { get; set; }
public string LblTitle { get; set; }
public string LblPlantLocation { get; set; }
public string LblUserLoggedInTimeStamp { get; set; }
public string LblUserLoggedOutTimeStamp { get; set; }
public string LblDisplayName { get; set; }
public string LblEmail { get; set; }

    
    //For the ArrayList of MemberGroups. 
    public ArrayList AuthorizationGroups { get; set; }
    public ArrayList YardDogUserGroupMembers { get; set; }
    public ArrayList MemberOfUserGroups { get; set; }
    public ArrayList YardDogAdminGroupMembers { get; set; }
    
    public object item { get; set; }
```

Razor CSHTML:

```
@model PW_Login.Models.UserLoginModel
@{
Layout = null;
/*
WebGrid webGrid = new WebGrid(source: Model, canPage: true, canSort: true, 
sortDirectionFieldName: "PlantLocation", rowsPerPage: 50);
webGrid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
*/

 }

 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<link href="~/Content/UserLogin.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>

@using (Html.BeginForm("UserLoginData", "LoginController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = 
"LoginDataForm", Class = "LoginDataForm" }))
{
    //Html.ListBoxFor(model=>model.AuthorizationGroups, Model.AuthorizationGroups)
    // string UserName = Session["UserName"].ToString();
    <label></label>
    //Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, @Model.UserName)

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserPlantLocation)
            </th>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <!--- Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AuthorizationGroups) -->
                    @foreach ( var item in Model.AuthorizationGroups)
            {
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(Modelitem=>item)
            }
                </td>
             
            </tr>
        
    </table>

}

</body>

</html>
```

Method that gets the info from AD in the Controller:

```
        private void ShowUserInformation(SearchResult rs, string UserName)
    {
        UserLoginModel model = new UserLoginModel();
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        model.UserName = UserName;
        Session["UserName"] = UserName;
        Session["LblUserName"] = UserName;

        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        string UserLoggedInTimeStamp = now.ToString();

        model.LblUserLoggedInTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt");

        //Push the UserName into the Label via the model.
        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samaccountname"].Value != null)
            model.LblUserName = "Username : " + 
        rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samaccountname"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["title"].Value != null)
            model.LblTitle = "Title : " + 
        rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["title"].Value.ToString();

        //description returns null... need to find out active directory folder/subfolder. 
        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["physicaldeliveryofficename"].Value != null) 
       //PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName returns 110.
            model.LblPlantLocation = "PlantLocation : " + 
       rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["physicaldeliveryofficename"].Value.ToString();
        
        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["member"].Value != null)
            model.LblMemberGroup = "Member : " + 
       rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["member"].Value.ToString();
        
        //DisplayName or DistinguishedName is what I do believe is in the security group 
       "YardDogUser" or "YardDogAdmin".
        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["distinguishedName"].Value != null)
            model.LblDistinguishedName = "distinguishedName : " + 
        rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["distinguishedName"].Value.ToString();
        //NULL... 
        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["YardDogAdmin"].Value != null)
            model.LblYardDogAdmin = "YardDogAdmin : " + 
        rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["YardDogAdmin"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["displayname"].Value != null)
            model.LblDisplayName = "Display Name : " + 
        rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["displayname"].Value.ToString();

        if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["email"].Value != null)
            model.lblEmail = "Email Address : " + 
        rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["email"].Value.ToString();

       
        /*
          //Member Of Office 365 Groups. Use if needed!
           ///ArrayList MemberOfGroups = new ArrayList();
          var MemberOfGroups = new ArrayList();  //perfered way of writing. 
          string Ret1 = string.Empty;
          foreach (object memberOf in rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["memberOf"])
          {
              MemberOfGroups.Add(Ret1 += " Member Of : " + memberOf.ToString() + "\n");
          }
                */

        //Get Security Groups that User belongs to. Note: Doesn't show other groups (won't 
        show YardDogAdmin). 
        ArrayList SecurityGroups = new ArrayList();

        foreach (IdentityReference group in 
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Groups)
        {
            SecurityGroups.Add(group.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString());
        }

        //model doesn't show the correct datetime on these. 
        model.LblUserLoggedInTimeStamp = model.UserLoggedInTimeStamp.ToString();
        model.LblUserLoggedOutTimeStamp = model.UserLoggedOutTimeStamp.ToString();

        /******************************************************************************/


        //Search to see if this group exists that starts with "YardDog". 
        using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {

            ArrayList FoundYardDogAdmin = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList SecurityGroupsFound = new ArrayList();
            // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a GroupPrincipal 
            // and with the name like some pattern
            GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);
            qbeGroup.Name = "YardDog*"; //Find all the User Groups for this User that is 
        logging in. 

            // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
            PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);
            string Ret4 = string.Empty;
            // find all matches
            foreach (var found in srch.FindAll())
            {
                FoundYardDogAdmin.Add(Ret4 += " GroupFound : " + found.ToString() + "\n");
                SecurityGroupsFound.Add(Ret4 += " GroupFound : " + qbeGroup.ToString() + 
      "\n");
            }
            //Count where the User's Display Name exists is needed next. We could do this here 
       or when we get all the Groups. 
        }

        //Search for all User's of YardDogAdmin Group and list them in the ArrayList. 
        /*
        using PrincipalContext ctxDomain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        {

            // get the group you're interested in
            GroupPrincipal GroupMembers = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity("YardDogAdmin");

            ArrayList GroupMembersArray = new ArrayList();

            // iterate over its members
            foreach (Principal principal in GroupMembers.Members)
            {
                GroupMembersArray.Add(principal);
            }
        }
        */
        /* Below works, finds all in YardDogAdmin's, YardDogUser's (Finds security groups by 
        string search). Use if needed.*/
        using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            //Groups to validate against for current User. 
           var GroupYardDogAdminPrincipalName = "YardDogAdmin";
            var GroupYardDogUserPrincipalName = "YardDogUser";
            //Find the current User's Groups. 
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, UserName);
            //Find all User's within these Groups. 
            GroupPrincipal YardDogAdminMembers = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, 
     GroupYardDogAdminPrincipalName);
            GroupPrincipal YardDogUserMembers = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, 
     GroupYardDogUserPrincipalName);
         
            //UserGroups that the User logged in belongs to. 
            if (user != null)
            {
                var MemberOfUserGroups = new ArrayList();
                model.MemberOfUserGroups = MemberOfUserGroups;
                var groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
                
                foreach (GroupPrincipal group in groups)
                {
                    MemberOfUserGroups.Add(group);
                }
                
                if (MemberOfUserGroups.Contains("YardDogAdmin"))
                {
      //Pass to the model YardDogAdmin exists for this user (AdminFlag translates to 
     LocationData table).
                    model.LblYardDogAdmin = "Y";
                    model.AdminFlag = "Y";

                }
                else
                {
                    model.LblYardDogAdmin = "N";
                    model.AdminFlag = "N";
                }

                //Get the Members of YardDogAdmin and their warehouse locations. 
                if (YardDogAdminMembers != null)
                {
                    var YardDogAdminGroupMembers = new ArrayList();
                    model.YardDogAdminGroupMembers = YardDogAdminGroupMembers;
                    foreach (Principal principal in YardDogAdminMembers.Members)
                    {
                     rs = SearchUserByDisplayName(principal.DisplayName.ToString());
                       YardDogAdminGroupMembers.Add(principal.DisplayName + " " + 
                         
    rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["physicaldeliveryofficename"].Value.ToString() + " 
           YardDogAdmin");
                    }
                }
                //Get the Members of YardDogUser and their location.
                if (YardDogUserMembers != null)
                {
                    var YardDogUserGroupMembers = new ArrayList();
                    model.YardDogUserGroupMembers = YardDogUserGroupMembers;
                    foreach (Principal principal in YardDogUserMembers.Members)
                    {
                        rs = SearchUserByDisplayName(principal.DisplayName.ToString());
                          YardDogUserGroupMembers.Add(principal.DisplayName + " " +
                            
      rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["physicaldeliveryofficename"].Value.ToString() + " 
      YardDogUser");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: See, this is why I'm strongly in favor of just removing these legacy classes like `ArrayList`. Let these people's code not compile anymore and clean up the framework. I mean this guy specifically seems to get paid by the `rs.GetDirectoryEntry()`, imagine how much more he'd get paid to rewrite his code correctly.

Comment: Some of these directory entries are objects embedded with other information. What would be suggested in rewriting this then?... I'm open to ideas to making better. An ArrayList is fast and gets the data by reference of that time is what I decided to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create TempData[] in the controller from one controller action result to another and then into the model also. After that you can access the TempData and keep it as needed for that session. Then on the Login Data Page, loop through the objects from the TempData or model properties to display in labels.

```
enter code here

@model PW_Login.Models.UserLoginModel
 @{
Layout = null;

string UserName = TempData["UserName"].ToString();
string PlantLocation = TempData["UserPlantLocation"].ToString();
string UserLoggedInTimeStamp = 
 TempData["UserLoggedInTimeStamp"].ToString();

//Get the TempData Sessions and write them out. 
var SecurityGroups = TempData["SecurityGroups"];
var MemberOfUserGroups = TempData["MemberOfUserGroups"];
var YardDogAdminGroupMembers = TempData["YardDogAdminGroupMembers"];
var YardDogUserGroupMembers = TempData["YardDogUserGroupMembers"];

TempData.Keep(UserLoggedInTimeStamp.ToString());
TempData.Keep(SecurityGroups.ToString());
TempData.Keep(MemberOfUserGroups.ToString());
TempData.Keep(YardDogAdminGroupMembers.ToString());
TempData.Keep(YardDogUserGroupMembers.ToString());


// PW_Login.Models.UserLoginModel LoginModel;

// LoginModel.SecurityGroups = SecurityGroups;

 }

 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>

<head>
<link href="~/Content/UserLogin.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 </head>
 <body>
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel2" HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <img id="PM_Logo" src="~/images/PremiumWatersLogo.PNG" />
</asp:Panel>

<h2>User Login Groups</h2><br /><br />
<div id="time"></div>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">

    function checkTime(i) {
            if (i < 10) {
                i = "0" + i;
            }
            return i;
        }
        function startTime() {
            var today = new Date();
            var h = today.getHours();
            var m = today.getMinutes();
            var s = today.getSeconds();

            // add a zero in front of numbers<10
            m = checkTime(m);
            s = checkTime(s);
            document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + 
  s; //Get the time.
            document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "Date: " + today; 
 //Get the Date.
            t = setTimeout(function () {
                startTime()
            }, 500);
        }
        startTime();
</SCRIPT>
@using (Html.BeginForm("UserLoginData", "LoginController", FormMethod.Post, 
  new { id = "LoginDataForm", Class = "LoginDataForm" }))
{

    <dv id="FlexLoginDataTables" class="FlexLoginDataTables">
        <table id="LoginDataTable" class="LoginDataTable">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.LabelForModel(UserName, "User Name: ")
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @foreach (var group in @Model.SecurityGroups)
                    {
                        <label id="LoginDataLabel" 
     class="LoginDataLabel">@group.ToString()</label><br />
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="LoginDataTable" class="LoginDataTable">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.YardDogAdminGroupMembers)
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @foreach (var group in @Model.YardDogAdminGroupMembers)
                    {
                        <label id="LoginDataLabel" 
     class="LoginDataLabel">@group.ToString()</label><br />
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <table id="LoginDataTable" class="LoginDataTable">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.YardDogUserGroupMembers)
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @foreach (var group in @Model.YardDogUserGroupMembers)
                    {
                        <label id="LoginDataLabel" 
    class="LoginDataLabel">@group.ToString()</label><br />
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </dv>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserLoggedInTimeStamp, 
     @Model.UserLoggedInTimeStamp)
            </th>
            <td>
                @Html.Label(@Model.UserLoggedInTimeStamp.ToString())
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="LoginDataTable" class="LoginDataTable">
        <tr>
            <th>
            </th>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

}

 </body>

 </html>
```